# Manejo de eventos de fecha y hora en Java

Tags: java

Quiero realizar una pequeña aplicación que me lance un `JFrame` a cierta hora del día pero no se como manejar eventos que puedan realizar esas acciones. Actualmente estoy utilizando un hilo para verificar cada cierto tiempo si esa es la hora a la que se debe lanzar el `JFrame`. ¿Existe una mejor manera de realizarlo?

Comment: Mejor utiliza una librería que administre trabajos como Quartz.

Comment: Mira , se realizo la misma pregunta en el foro en ingles ingles:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814089/how-to-schedule-a-periodic-task-in-java

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la API de `Timer` y `TimerTask`.

El avisador:

```
public class FrameAdvisor {

    public final static int AD_HOUR = 13; // 13 horas o 1PM
    private Timer timer;

    public FrameAdvisor() {
        timer = new Timer();
        // comprobará cada hora
        timer.schedule(new FrameAdvisorTask(), 100000);
    }
}
```

El timer que se estará ejecutando cada 1 hora:

```
public FrameAdvisorTask extends TimerTask {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        FrameOffert offert;
        int hourOfDay;

        hourOfDay = DateUtil.getHourOfDay();
        if(FrameAdvisor.AD_HOUR == hourOfDay) {
            offert = new FrameOffert();
            offert.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Clase utilitaria:

```
public final class DateUtils {

    private DateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

    public static int getHourOfDay() {
        String strDate = fmt.format(new Date());
        String hour = strDate.subString(0, 2);
        return Integer.parseInt(hour);
    }

}
```

Comment: Así es, problema de escritura. No probé el código, fue solo para que sirva de guía al OP si es que le sirve como tal.